# Understanding HttpServletRequest and cookies in JSF

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, cookies

In order to create a "Remember me" login in JSF, I am trying to understand how Cookies work. I have created a brand new Web Application using JSF, with this bean that creates a Cookie expiring with the session:

**CookieBean** class

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CookieBean implements Serializable {
    public void create() {
        ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        ec.addResponseCookie("MyTestCookie", "Hello Cookie", null);
    }    
}
```

and **index.xhtml** has this body:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Create Cookie!" action="#{cookieBean.create()}" >
        <f:ajax render="@form" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <p></p>
    <h:outputText value="Cookie value: #{cookie['MyTestCookie'].value}" /> 
</h:form>
```

As a result, when the page first loads, there is no cookie, correctly, because it's the first time the application runs, and no cookie is there.

After clicking the button once, no cookie is displayed. Why? The button invokes the `cookieBean#create()` method, and the ajax tag should force a revaluation of the `outputText` component. And this should generate an `HttpSerlvetRequest` with the cookie... or not? The cookie shows only after I press the button again!.

More surprisingly, when I press the `refresh` button of the browser, the cookie is not shown, although I'd expect to see it, because the older session is still alive.

It's like if (re)loading the page doesn't send an HttpServletRequest to the server...

Comment: Do you see the cookie in the browser's dev tools?

Comment: When I don't see the cookie in the web app, there is no POST in firebug either. On the contrary, when I see the cookie in the web app, the POST is visible in firebug with its cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#{cookie}` refers to the cookies of the **current HTTP request**. If you add a new cookie, then it appears only on the HTTP response, but the HTTP request which is associated with this HTTP response does of course not have the cookie yet. It's only present in the subsequent request, depending on the age of the cookie.

You basically need to send a redirect afterwards to make the cookie available during rendering the HTTP response for the HTTP request.

As to the refresh matter, the request was most likely re-executed in the browser cache.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC but I am not sure to understand. I thought the ajax would produce a new request... However let's put it in the other way: even if I set a positive maxAge to the cookie, the behaviour of my app is the same. So how can I catch the cookie on page load in order to implement Remember Me like StackOverflow site?

Comment: Ajax or not, the new cookie is set in the response of the associated request. But the `#{cookie}` refers to the cookies of *that* request and it's of course not in there yet, simply because the client wasn't aware of the new cookie at the moment the request is been sent.

Comment: Ok, this is reasonable. Thanks. I have successfully caught the cookie using a WebFilter.