# WebFilter, EL and SessionScoped ManagedBean to handle Remember Me login

Tags: java, jsf, cookies, managed-bean

This question is related to another one that I posted recently: [Understanding HttpServletRequest and cookies in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567277/understanding-httpservletrequest-and-cookies-in-jsf) .

In order to implement a **Remember Me** login in `JSF`, I am using a cookie and reading it in `WebFilter`. The filter gets the cookie and sets the cookie value in the `SessionScoped` `ManagedBean`, but for some reason the `ManagedBean` isn't able to display it in the web page.

Filter's **doFilter** implementation:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            if (cookie.getName().equals("MyTestCookie")) {
                System.out.println("Filter got cookie: " + cookie.getValue());
                cookieBean.setValue(cookie.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

**CookieBean** class:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class CookieBean implements Serializable {

    private String value;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Instantiated CookieBean");
    }

    public String getValue() {
        System.out.println("CookieBean returning Value: " + value);
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        System.out.println("CookieBean getting Value: " + value);
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void create() {
        ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        props.put("maxAge", 10000);
        ec.addResponseCookie("MyTestCookie", "Hello Cookie", props);
    }    
}
```

`CookieBean` `cookieBean` is injected into the filter by means of `javax.inject.Inject` annotation.

Body of **index.xhtml**:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Create Cookie!" action="#{cookieBean.create()}" >
        <f:ajax render="@form" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <p></p>
    <h:outputText value="Cookie value: #{cookieBean.value}" /> 
</h:form>
```

The first problem is that, after setting the cookie, if I start a new session (by opening a new browser session), the web page isn't aware of the cookie value, because the `SessionScoped` `ManagedBean` is updated *after* the page is displayed.

**Question 1**: how can I detect the cookie value in time to update some `rendered` attribute in the web page?

The second problem is that, if I reload the web page by pressing the reload (or refresh) button in the browser, the ManagedBean instance is the same as before (the `@PostConstruct` method isn't fired), but the web page shows a null cookie value and the same is shown in the server's output:

```
CookieBean returning Value: null
Filter got cookie: Hello Cookie
CookieBean getting Value: Hello Cookie
```

**Question 2**: how is it possible that a `SessionScoped` `ManagedBean` loses its property without being re-created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to Question 1**: as explained in the accepted answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567277/understanding-httpservletrequest-and-cookies-in-jsf), I simply had to do a redirect in the backing bean. This forces JSF to produce a new GET request with the cookie in. Supposing that the requesting page was my welcome page, I had to write this in my `cookieBean`:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("faces/index.xhtml");
```

Well, this works nicely, but the complete URL is now shown in the address bar. I'll investigate further if there is a way for avoiding this.

**Answer to Question 2**: the `SessionScoped` `cookieBean` was effectively instantiated twice, one during deployment, and one by the filter. The problem is that I was using a JSF ManagedBean and injecting it with `javax.inject.Inject` annotation. I have made it a CDI Bean by means of `javax.inject.Named` and `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` annotations, and the injection is now working well.